# PCF buildpack for external api

Tags: cloud-foundry, documentum, pcf

I am new to PCF and and i am working on documentum based application means my spring application using documentum APIs, In local my microservice is working fine but when i pushed my app in PCFDEV it is throwing error like classNotFoundException for external API, I am assuming i have to create buildpack for my external API and use that while pushing the app.

Can someone help me to clear my query here?

Comment: Are there jars you need installed within your jdk (e.g. ext folder)?
If so, can you bundle them with your spring jar and push everything?)

Comment: Or something on the classpath on running your app which is not on compile classpath. So if you push to pcf jdk inside pcfdev cannot find these runtime dependencies?